# Use Bulma to make a div in the middle fills the remaining space and scroll

Tags: html, css, less, bulma

I've started to use **Bulma** 0.7.1.

Now, I'm trying to design a template that resembles an IDE, i.e. with fixed navbars, asides and footers and a scrollable are in the middle. I have some problems in making the container that should fill the visible space and scroll if necessary.

I've tried to apply a custom css class

```
.vscrollable {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to the containers that should scroll

I've done [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJzKjQ) in Codepen and reported here for simplicity. The HTML part is:

```
<section class="section">
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-start">
       <a class="navbar-item">Home</a>
       <a class="navbar-item">Bla1</a>
       <a class="navbar-item">Bla2</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<div class="columns">
  <aside class="column is-3 has-background-warning">
    <div class="panel vscrollable">
       I have some special content that
  Very special. I should be scrollable vertically
  and horizontallyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      <h1>bla</h1>
      <h1>bla</h1>
      <h1>bla</h1>
      <h1>bla</h1>
      <h1>bla</h1>
    </div>          
  </aside>
  <section class="column">
  <!-- This will contain another navbar and the scrollable container -->
      <nav class="navbar has-background-link">
        <div class="navbar-start">
           <a class="navbar-item">Yet another link</a>
           <a class="navbar-item">And another</a>
           <a class="navbar-item">And another one</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <section class="section">
        <div class="container vscrollable">
          <p>This should be scrollable vertically and horizontally and fill the available space</p>
                <h1>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablaneverendingtextblablablablablabla</h1>
                <h1>bla</h1>
                <h1>bla</h1>
                <h1>bla</h1>
                <h1>bla</h1>
        </div>          
      </section>  
  </section>
</div>
<footer class="footer has-background-danger">
  <div class="content has-text-centered">
    <p>
      This is a footer. it contains nice stuff
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I'd like to find a solution based on Bulma css classes, but also a custom one based on css3 or less is ok.